# Spring ApplicationContextShutdownBean entries in log

Tags: logging, springsource-dm-server

My SpringSource dm Server log is full of lines like the following:

```
com.springsource.server.kernel.dm.ApplicationContextShutdownBean < void com.springsource.server.kernel.dm.ApplicationContextShutdownBean.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent)
```

making it hard to spot interesting log events.

How can I turn these log entries off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you suppress it via config/server.config?

"serviceability": {
            "trace": {
                "directory": "serviceability/trace",
                "levels": {
                   **"com.springsource.server.kernel.dm.ApplicationContextShutdownBean" : "warn",**
                    "*" : "info"